# Numpy: How to check if array contains certain numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

For example: I have `a = np.array([123, 412, 444])`
and `b = np.array([123, 321])`

I want to know if `a` contains **all** the elements in `b`. Is there a simple operation for this? In this case that would not be true.

Comment: Do you mean unique elements? a = [3,3,4], b = [3,4,5], are all elements of a contained in b?

Comment: No I meant that all the elements in b has to be in a. The answers below where what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use set difference to determine what you are looking for. Numpy has a built-in function called [numpy.setdiff1d(ar1, ar2)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

> Return the sorted, unique values in ar1 that are not in ar2.

Example for your case:

```
>>> a = np.array([123, 412, 444])
>>> b = np.array([123, 321])
>>> diff = np.setdiff1d(b, a)
>>> print diff
array([321])
>>> if diff.size:
>>>    print "Not passed"
```

So for your case, you would do a set difference you would subtract a from b and obtain an array with elements in b which are not in a. Then you can check if that was empty or not. As you can see, the output is `312`, which is an entry present in `a` but not in `b`; the length of it is now larger then zero, therefore there were elements in `b` which were not present in `a`.

Comment: @luffe if I answered your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: @petr better to check `if diff` instead

Comment: @petr, do you mean `321` instead of `312` for array elements which are in `b` but not in `a`?

Answer (score 14):

You could alway use a set:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([123, 412, 444])
>>> b = numpy.array([123, 321])
>>> set(b) in set(a)
False
```

Or with newer versions of numpy:

```
>>> numpy.in1d(b,a)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

If you want just 'the answer' rather than an array:

```
>>> numpy.in1d(b,a).all()
False
```

Or (least desirable):

```
>>> numpy.array([x in a for x in b]) 
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Looping is slowish on numpy arrays and should be avoided.

Comment: `set(b) in set(a)` probably doesn't do what you want, that would be `set.is[super|sub]set`.

Answer (score 5):

that means you want to check if each element of b is contained in a.
[`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) does that:

```
from numpy import array, in1d
a = array([123, 412, 444])
b = array([123, 321])
print in1d(b, a).all()
```

Update from 2021: nowadays [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) is recommended

Answer (score -1):

you could do:

```
 a = an_array
 b = another_array
 for i in b:
    if i not in a:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: That is not valid Python. Also, a Python loop on a numpy array is very slow.

Comment: how exactly is that invalid python?

Comment: Obviously you have not run it in the interpreter. If you had done so you would have discovered your code raises a `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`.