# How to check efficiently if numpy array a contains b

Tags: python, numpy

How to check if one numpy array a contains fully another numpy array b efficiently?
Somewhat like b is subset of a....

Thanks!

EDIT:
a and b are one dimentional numpy arrays

Comment: @jterrace yes a and b are one dimentional

Comment: can either a or b contain repeated values?

Comment: maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565598/numpy-how-to-check-if-array-contains-certain-numbers)

Comment: @neel101 Do you need to check if each element of b exists in a, or if b exists in a as a (consecutive) sub-array?

Comment: just only want to check if each element of b exist in a... and your answer worked thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're asking about `b` being a *consecutive sub-array* of `a`**

If either of the arrays can contain repeated values, algorithmically speaking, your problem is equivalent to a [single-pattern string-searching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Single_pattern_algorithms). There are several known algorithms for this problem.  Unfortunately, neither is too simple.

Else, it is simple to implement, by first looking for the first element in `b`, then comparing all the following elements:

```
import numpy as np

def is_subarray_no_repeatition(a, b):
  try:
    i = np.where(a == b[0])[0][0]
  except IndexError:
    # either b is empty, or b[0] not in a
    return b.size == 0
  a = a[i : i+b.size]
  if a.size < b.size:
    return False
  return (a == b).all()
```

---

**If you're asking about `b` being a *subset* of `a` (i.e. that each element of `b` exists in `a`)**

```
def is_subset(a, b):
  b = np.unique1d(b)
  c = np.intersect1d(a,b)
  return c.size == b.size
```

Comment: Isn't there any function in numpy that can do this job? I was using np.intersect1d(a, b) == b: which unfortunately was giving shape mismatch error